# Restrict the shop_manager role to the WooCommerce Orders Page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-roles, permissions

I want to show only the **woocommerce orders page** to `shop_manager` role, and restrict users with the `shop_manager` to only that admin page.

If not show them this message: `Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.`

How would I do this?

Comment: > _I want do this programatically_

What's the way you want it? Free of charge or Open Source?

Comment: @MaxYudin Sorry. I did not understand your meaning

Comment: When you want to make a plugin, you already have some code? Are you? This is useless to ask for help here with no code written. Nobody will write for free, like you will not. Make a try. And what is the problem to google for "wordpress check capabilities".

Comment: @MaxYudin be nice, Saeid may be unaware of the capabilities system, it's a good opportunity to explain in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution.

```
function checkUserPermissionsInThisScreen(){
    if (is_admin()){

        $currentUserRoles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;
        if (in_array('shop_manager', $currentUserRoles)){

            $a = get_current_screen();
            if ($a->id != 'edit-shop_order' && $a->post_type != 'shop_order'){
                wp_die('you do not have needed permissions to see this page');
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('current_screen', 'checkUserPermissionsInThisScreen');
```